# main.CRITICAL: Class block does not exist error in log files but extension works?

Tags: layout, extensions, custom-extension

I have a working extension that show reviews, but sometimes there's an error in the system.log file, and I don't know why?

**var/log/system.log:**

```
[2023-10-26T11:20:42.925466+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Class "Company\AllReviews\Block\AllReviews" does not exist [] []
```

**The extension resides in:**

```
\app\code\Company\Reviews\Block\AllReviews.php
\app\code\Company\Reviews\Block\Reviews.php
```

The file `AllReviews.php` ( *allreviews.phtml*) shows all reviews, and `Reviews.php` (*reviews.phtml*) only shows the 25 latest reviews.

**Layout file:**

```
\app\design\frontend\Smartwave\company_default\Magento_Review\layout\default.xml


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="reviews">
        <block class="Company\Reviews\Block\Reviews" template="magento_review::reviews.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="allreviews">
        <block class="Company\Reviews\Block\AllReviews" template="magento_review::allreviews.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Template files location:**

```
\app\design\frontend\Smartwave\company_default\Magento_Review\templates\allreviews.phtml
\app\design\frontend\Smartwave\company_default\Magento_Review\templates\reviews.phtml
```

**--- post update ---**

This is the beginning of the file *AllReviews.php*

```
<?php
namespace Company\Reviews\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class AllReviews extends Template {
protected $customerSession;
protected $_storeManager;
...
```

This is the beginning of the file *Reviews.php*

```
<?php
namespace Company\Reviews\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Reviews extends Template {
protected $customerSession;
protected $_storeManager;
...
```

Comment: Can you share the code of these two files as well : \app\code\Company\Reviews\Block\AllReviews.php
\app\code\Company\Reviews\Block\Reviews.php

Comment: I have updated to post with some PHP code from AllReviews.php and Reviews.php (the files are huge, hoping this is enough?). Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems to be **namespace issue** somewhere in your file you can track using "**grep -r 'AllReviews'**" in your files and then replace with **Reviews** and also in your **default.xml** file change the template name **magento_review** to **Magento_Review**.

Comment: Can't see any issues since we flushed the Redis db's and changed the template names with capital letters.  Thank you!